# It says that my code is wrong but WHY?

Tags: javascript

The instruction for my code is this:

> Make the computer start counting at 8. Keep counting while i < 120. Count up by increments of 12.

This is my code:

```js
for (var i = 8 ; i < 120; i++) {  
  console.log(i += 12); 
}
```

It says that it is wrong, but why???

Comment: "It says". What is it?

Comment: @EvanTrimboli He needs a increment of 12 not 13 as his code outputs 20, 33.

Answer (score 2):

`i++` is give the increment of `1` on each time. Add the `i += 12` and try your answer .

DO like this:

```js
for (var i = 8 ; i < 120;  i +=12 ) {
  console.log(i);
}
```

Comment: I tried the code but it still says that my loop didn't log 8 into the console

Comment: This answer is help full don't forget to mark as answer(left side tick mark). Its helpfull  for future visitors

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to the following error in the code snippet console, after clicking the <kbd>Run code snippet</kbd> button:

```
Error: {
  "message": "Script error.",
  "filename": "",
  "lineno": 0,
  "colno": 0
}
```

...or the following error in the browser console:

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'cookie' property from 'Document': The document is sandboxed and lacks the 'allow-same-origin' flag.

...you can find an explanation on [StackOverflow META: “Sandbox access violation” error in Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317335/sandbox-access-violation-error-in-stack-snippet).